# Difference between hostname -i and /etc/hosts

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, webserver

To cut a long story short my colleague and i are having a miserable time trying to get jconsole to connect to our dev box via a remote connection (even though for me the dev box is on my network)

Essentially we found the following guide stating

> So start jconsole in debugging mode (jconsole -debug from a terminal).
>   If you see a local (from server point of view) ip (e.g. 127.0.1.1) you
>   must go on server, type hostname -i and see how the hostname it’s
>   resolved by the server (e.g. 127.0.1.1). Then you must change the row
>   of etc/hosts file where the server hostname is translated into the
>   local ip (127.0.1.1). You can delete the row and use the DNS or insert
>   the server ip.

When we checked the value in `/etc/hosts` was different to the value for `hostname -i` - is this correct and if not should `/etc/hosts` be modified to reflect `hostname -i`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they are telling you to use the actual IP address for the host, not the loopback addresses assigned to the hostname (127.0.1.1) or localhost(127.0.0.1). if your boxes IP is 192.168.5.5 you would put that in the hosts file. if your network dynamically assigns IP addresses, use the DNS name for the box, so that it gets automatically resolved even if the ip assignment changes.

so assuming your box is named 'BOX1' and its IP is 192.168.5.5 you would have a line in your hosts file like:

```
192.168.5.5     BOX1
```

or you can ignore all of this, and simply delete the line mapping BOX1 to 127.0.0.1, but this may interfere with other applications.

Comment: sorry for this potentially stupid question - would the box ip then be the ip on my network or my public facing ip? and would box name just be the `hostname` i asigned

Comment: the local network address. don't use the public address. and yes, the hostname you defined when setting up the server. on the box I'm working on now, I would replace the line like `Minty-chan     127.0.0.1` with the line `Minty-chan     10.0.8.17` which is the LAN IP for this box. hope that helps